# liferay use service/class from ext plugin in portlet

Tags: liferay, portlet

I have created a liferay custom MVC portlet which is required to call some services/classes defined by someone else in an ext plugin already deployed on the server. Does anyone know what is needed to resolve the "class/service not found" errors?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an EXT plugin is deployed the classes inside `ext-<plugin-name>-ext-service.jar` can be accessed by any plugin since it this goes in the global class-path (`/tomcat/lib/ext` for tomcat) just like `portal-service.jar` of liferay.

But the classes inside `ext-<plugin-name>-ext-impl.jar` can only be accessed by EXT and hook JSPs (if any), since it is similar to `portal-impl.jar` since this resides in `\tomcat\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib` which is in the portal class-path.

So if you are accessing classes inside `ext-impl.jar`, which seems to be the case then I am sorry to say **but you are out of luck**.

May be some work around can be found if you can provide more information.

Comment: I have created a custom portlet which runs a scheduler every 10 minutes; this scheduler is importing records into a DDL from a text file. The portal also has a hook which overrides the functionality of the DDL portlet, and when you add new records from its interface, it automatically calls the method of a class which then calls a service, both deployed inside the ext. When I'm creating new records via the Importer portlet (my portlet), the same steps need to be made so that everything will run fine: call the class defined in the ext, which will call the other service.

Comment: I forgot to say that both the class and the service have been defined in the ext-impl folder of the ext plugin. Thanks a lot for the quick response earlier!

Comment: You might need to copy the classes to your portlet from `ext-impl` and also copy dependencies. But if you are using a lot of classes from `portal-impl` then this does not seem to be an option. You can try to refactor and see if all the services can be moved to your portlet or to ext-service. I can only think of this as of now.

Comment: Yes, I thought this was the only solution, but I'm not sure it's feasible. Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I have managed a work-around for this problem. I have worked directly with the database from my portlet, instead of using the service, and have copied the java functions needed from the ext to my portlet. This has solved it.